# Calling Bash Commands From Ruby with russian symbols return 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, mediainfo

Calling bash command

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/mediainfo "/var/avalon/dropbox/Лекции_для_молодых_ученых/Nabiullin_SciERes_1.flv" --Output=XML'    
out = `#{cmd}`
```

In rails project **`'avalom media system'`** return **error code** 1.

Removal of russian letters out of the path `cmd = '/usr/bin/mediainfo "/var/avalon/dropbox/Nabiullin_SciERes_1.flv" --Output=XML'` , a call to another command 
    `cmd = 'head "/var/avalon/dropbox/Лекции_для_молодых_ученых/Nabiullin_SciERes_1.flv"'` 
     or run the command in irb or project environment or bash 
      - everything is fine.

Thx.

*Error when i try add media file to collection with russian letters in  [file:543](https://github.com/avalonmediasystem/avalon/blob/master/app/models/master_file.rb) => in gem media info [file:473](https://github.com/greatseth/mediainfo/blob/master/lib/mediainfo.rb)*

*Console encoding - utf-8. Command string encoding - utf-8.*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to run this command?

Comment: I described the problem. And it is obvious that I want to solve it. And the question is how to do it and what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Is calling the command directly from bash prompt executed successfully?

Comment: Yes, it is. _or run the command in irb or project environment or bash 
  - everything is fine._

Comment: What produces the text `Removal of russian letters out of the path`? It's difficult to tell if this is output from `avalon`, your own project, or a comment by you.

Comment: its moderator editions. i means that if command didnt contain russian litters that command return 0. same if run it from bash or irb etc. sorry for my eng.(

Comment: I setup avalon. Try to fill it with my sample. When add media file to collection catch error (italic in main post).  And now I try understand  what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Okey. New quest =)
I saved path to file path.tmp (utf-8).
Run this command ``"/usr/bin/mediainfo `head /var/avalon/dropbox/path.tmp` --Output=XML"`` from bash - return ok. run this command in avalon instead of create mediainfo object - return faild (1). run this command from rails console in avalon environment - return ok.

Comment: `ENV["LANG"]` from rails console in avalon environment = `"en_US.UTF-8"`, from avalon's master_file.rb `"C"`. Mb this is key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that `ENV["LANG"]` of avalon is `C`. 
Set ENV["LANG"] to `en_US.utf-8` resolve this trouble.